# Binding vclick to url's with a class

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to bind `vclick` to my links with a class of "vclick" so the responses are very fast. how do i do that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body >

  <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"><a data-transition="slide" href="#page2" class="vclick">go to page 2</a></div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"><a data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" href="#page" class="vclick">back to page one</a></div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I learnt `vclick` makes touches responses very faster

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery FastClick https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

> FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers. The aim is to make your application feel less laggy and more responsive while avoiding any interference with your current logic.